# SAP Cloud Application Programming Model Integration

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-cap

I try to integrate already implemented `SAPUI5` application with `CAP` in order to use `SQLite` database. In my models I have a property called `Order` and as you may know, `Order` is a reserved keyword in `SQLite`.

```
entity MyEntity{
  key ID : Integer;
  Name: localized String(111);
  Order: Integer;
}
```

When I try to use the following command to generate the database:

```
cds deploy --to sqlite:db/mydb.db
```

I get the syntax error:

```
[ERROR] SQLITE_ERROR: near "Order": syntax error
```

When I use the quotation in my defined entity, then I get an error which regards to SAP `HANA` database:

```
[ERROR] cds compile failed due to these errors...
 at db\schema.cds:23:3-10: Quoted identifiers are not allowed in plain mode of toHana: "Order"
```

I just wanted to know is there anyway to solve the issue?

PS: I do not want to use `HANA` database, so please let me know if there is anyway to disable it, because I could not find any information in this regards.

I appreciate any help or advice :)

Comment: add your package.json here

Answer (score 0):

In the package.json of your application's root folder, you might have mentioned HANA as the productive DB 'kind'. Try changing it to SQLite.

Comment: No it's sqlite. I guess because they actually believe we should use HANA in production, by default it also check the HANA compatibility. I see such a different behaviors also in Node.js OData version.